# Is there any way I can get the HAR information with js?

Tags: javascript, performance, har

I was wondering if there is some way that I can get through js the HAR information collected by the browser.

The idea is that in some cases I can send these back to the server so we can better monitor browser loading times of our customers.

Answer (score 2):

There is not but you should check out google telemetry for creating reproducible performance load tests.

- [catapult telemetry](https://chromium.googlesource.com/catapult/+/HEAD/telemetry/README.md) on chromium.googlesource.com
- Adobes Top Coat is also a good project to check out. It has graphs and a web interface on top of telemetry.

Its good to focus on reproducible tests so when the code is changed you can see if it's faster or slower. There are only 2 thing the real world that affect you front-end: spikes in server load (which you should use JMeter other tools to metric / monitor) and latency (which you have no control over). Since any HAR file is just from a single computer you can test that in controlled environments and show gains/loses.

Comment: +1 on pointing out telemetry. this will likely make my previous need to work with the .har files irrelevant.